Variable dropped for collinearity in feols package in R (TWFE)
sorry if this is a basic question (I'm new to econometrics). I have the following regression model:
$Y_{i,t} = \alpha_i + \gamma_t + \beta_1\cdot X_{1,i,t} + \beta_2 \cdot X_{2,i} + \beta_3 \cdot X_{3,i,t} + \epsilon_{i,t}$
where ( i ) symbolizes countries and ( t ) symbolizes time in years. $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are my independent variables.
I want to calculate the coefficients of this regression when $X_2$ changes between different countries, but not over time. The current model I'm running in R drops my $X_2$ variable due to collinearity, and I think it is because $X_2$ doesn't change over time.
This is my regression formula:
fit_fe <- feols(Donation_per_pop ~ Type_opt  + percentage_catholics + GDP | Country + Year , data=data_clean_na, se=vcov_cluster())
How can I properly include $X_2$ (percentage_catholics) in my TWFE regression model without it being dropped due to collinearity?
Thanks

When you include country fixed effects $\alpha_i$ in your model you include a dummy variable for each country.
However, you cannot have a dummy variable for each $i$, and still identify the coefficient $\beta_2$ on the variable $X_{2i}$ that only varies across $i$. The coefficient $\beta_2$ on $X_{2i}$ can only be identified by cross-section variation - the variation across countries - because it has no time variation. However, all that variation is captured by the fixed effects $\alpha_i$.
It is easy to see this. Consider the fact that for each $i$ you can simply set $\lambda_i=\beta_2X_{i2} + \alpha_i$ then the model becomes
$Y_{i,t} = \lambda_i + \gamma_t + \beta_1\cdot X_{1,i,t} + \beta_3 \cdot X_{3,i,t} + \epsilon_{i,t},$
the model you want to estimate is indistinguishable from a model with another value of the fixed effects but without $\beta_2X_{i2}$.

Jesper: Nice answer. I can see that $X_{2,i}$ doesn't vary over time but how can you tell that it doesn't vary within country so for a given $i$. ? In other words, isn't it possible that there are multiple observations of $X_{2,i}$ for a given $i$ because there are multiple observations of $Y_{i,t}$ for a given $i$ and given $t$. Maybe not but how do you know that ? Thanks.

If there is variation for a single country across time the notation is wrong and $X_{2i}$ should be $X_{2it}$. Obviously, then there is time-variation and the coefficient is identified. If there are multiple observations for given $i$ and $t$ for example by subregions of a country I would still say the notation is wrong and should be $Y_{itc}$ and $X_{2ic}$ where $c$ is region. It is much more likely that the person has a country-panel data set (especially because if the situation you mention were the case R would not kick the variable due to perfect multicollinearity)

So I know because (1) I assume people write what they mean and (2) R drops due to collinearity which is inconsistent with the option you suggest.

The notation is not wrong if there are multiple observations in a country given $i$ and $t$. The $c$ subscript that you introduce is not necessary. But, given the message about collinearity, I would tend to think that there are not multiple observations also. So, your answer is most likely correct.

Indexation is functional notation. $X_{2i}$ is used to indicate that given $i$ there is one and one value for the variable $X_2$ so yes it is wrong if you assume that there is more than one value given the country (example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704059/are-indexed-symbols-just-evaluated-functions)

I don't have time to read and understand what you linked to but thanks for it. When I have a lot of time, I'll check it out. It looks deep.   I was talking about more from an R call standpoint. but I'm also not familiar with feols which may require different notation from say a call to lm ? lm relies on the standard formula grammar from S+ but feols could be different. In the lm call, if you conditioned on country and year, then you wouldn't need a region variable. There could be multiple observations for country and year and things would just work.
